# How to make a Windows-like button design in JavaFX?

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, javafx

I'm currently making a program and I was wondering how I could attain this Windows-like button in JavaFX?

[image]

Comment: Ignoring the JavaFX part, using a GUI builder makes things much easier.  Layouts can get very complicated in real applications and using a builder removes about 80% of it, at least.  I *think* there's a similar too for JavaFX but I'm not familiar with it to be sure: https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html

Comment: This appears to be a [similar tool for JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/overview/jsbpub-overview.htm) and this appears to get you started with the [Netbeans version of the JavaFX tool.](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/use_java_ides/sb-with-nb.htm#CIHDHEFE)

Comment: [Does JavaFX have a "native look and feel" option like Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968409/does-javafx-have-a-native-look-and-feel-option-like-swing)

Comment: @markspace For a WYSIWYG editor for JavaFX, the only real game in town, that I'm aware of, is [Scene Builder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) (current release is version 18 by Gluon, not Oracle). Though it creates FXML files instead of code.

Comment: if you just want the button, then just use [Sai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74010540/1155209).  If you want more controls that look and act like the Windows standard controls, then look at [JMetro](https://pixelduke.com/java-javafx-theme-jmetro/#How_to_get_it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the css styling of the button.

Please check the below css code to apply the desired styles on the button.
[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WindowsButtonCssDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button b1 = new Button("OK");
        Button b2 = new Button("Cancel");
        HBox.setHgrow(b1, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(b2, Priority.ALWAYS);

        HBox row = new HBox(b1, b2);
        row.setSpacing(5);
        StackPane root =new StackPane(row);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#1F1F1F;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400,200);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("button.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle("Windows Button");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**CSS code:**

```
.button{
    -fx-max-width: infinity;
    -fx-background-color: #4D4D4D;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0px;
    -fx-text-fill: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-font-size:14px;
}
```